# return from hook function hangs

Tags: c, dlsym

I have hooked my own fopen function which calls fopen through dlsym .The process hangs after the execution of the function .Have been searching on internet and couldn't get more information on this . Have put prints in the code and there's hang during the function return .

```
FILE *mfopen(const char *pathname, const char *mode){

FILE * (*dfopen)(const char *, const char *);

  void *handle;
  FILE *fp;
  char *error;

  printf("dlopen function \n");

  handle = dlopen ("/lib32/libc.so.6", RTLD_NOW);

  if(!handle){

    printf("Unable to open -->fopen library \n");
    printf("fopen error = %s \n",dlerror());
    return NULL;   

  }

   printf("dlsym call  \n");
  //dfopen = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"fopen");
  dfopen = dlsym(handle,"fopen");

 if((error = dlerror()) != NULL){

     printf("fopen failure \n");
     return NULL;    
  }

  dlclose(handle);

  printf("fopen call  \n");
  fp = (*dfopen)(pathname,mode);


  printf("return call  \n");
  return fp;
}
```

output

```
dlsym call  
fopen call  
return call  
***
```

Comment: The problem might exist in the calling function, which you didn't quote. Also you could try option RTLD_NOLOAD -- just to be safe (you don't need two different libc's, they won't cooperate)

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are calling dlclose immediately after dlsym and then are trying to call the function at the address returned by dlsym. This is incorrect and leads to the problem.

When you do a dlclose, there is a high possibility that the OS will remove the shared library from memory and the address returned from dlsym may no longer be active unless there are other dlopen's active for the library which is causing the OS to keep the library in memory.

Nevertheless, better follow the practice of calling dlclose only after all the work on the address retured from dlsym is complete and you have nothing further to do with the library.

Comment: i tried closing before the return too , still the same problem

Comment: But, you might still be trying to use the "fp" returned from dlsym which basically came from the library. You should call dlclose only when your work with "fp" is also over and you have nothing further to do with the lib.